# Change the NA to part of the string in another column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I want to extract some of the strings in a specific column and replace NA.
For the data.frame below, I want to extract the string in another column when the email information is NA.
The string is always between 'developer_id=' and '&app_id' in column 'Subject'.

```
    |Email      |  Subject                                    |
    |a@site.com |  developer_id=a@site.com&app_id=a&appname=a |
    |NA         |  developer_id=b@site.com&app_id=b&appname=b |
    |c@site.com |  NA                                         |
    |NA         |  developer_id=d@site.com&app_id=d&appname=d |
```

The results I expect are as follows.

```
    |Email      |  Subject                                    |
    |a@site.com |  developer_id=a@site.com&app_id=a&appname=a |
    |b@site.com |  developer_id=b@site.com&app_id=b&appname=b |
    |c@site.com |  NA                                         |
    |d@site.com |  developer_id=d@site.com&app_id=d&appname=d |
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `base R` would be to extract the substring of the second column that corresponds to the `NA` elements in first column and update the first column `NA` elements with the value extracted

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$Email) # create a logical index
df1$Email[i1] <- regmatches(df1$Subject[i1], 
                   regexpr("[a-z]+@.*\\.com", df1$Subject[i1]))
df1
#       Email                                    Subject
#1 a@site.com developer_id=a@site.com&app_id=a&appname=a
#2 b@site.com developer_id=b@site.com&app_id=b&appname=b
#3 c@site.com                                       <NA>
#4 d@site.com developer_id=d@site.com&app_id=d&appname=d
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Email = case_when(is.na(Email) ~ str_extract(Subject, "[a-z]+@.*\\.com"), 
                  TRUE ~ Email))
```

Also, as the OP mentioned about separate strings as identifiers, we can use regex lookaround along those strings i.e. to extract all characters that succeeds the `developer_id=` and precedes `&app_id`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(Email = case_when(is.na(Email) ~ 
         str_extract(Subject, "(?<=developer_id\\=).*(?=&app_id)"), 
        TRUE ~ Email))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Email = c("a@site.com", NA, "c@site.com", NA), 
Subject = c("developer_id=a@site.com&app_id=a&appname=a", 
"developer_id=b@site.com&app_id=b&appname=b", NA, 
  "developer_id=d@site.com&app_id=d&appname=d"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

As your request,

1. When `Subject == NA`, `Email = Email`
2. When `Subject != NA`, *extract* string

   - between `developer_id=`
   - and `&app_id`

This extraction can be done by function `stringr::str_extract(x, pattern)`

using regular expression `pattern = "(?<=developer_id=).*(?=&app_id)"`.

The first part `(?<=developer_id=)` would find characters *followed by* `developer_id=`. `.*` means any character after this pattern. After that, `(?=&app_id)` would match characters followed by `&app_id`.

In other words, we can find the part between `developer_id=` and `&app_id` that you want.

Using `dplyr::mutate` and `ifelse()`, you might easily transform the given column.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr, stringr
mydf %>% # your data
  mutate(Email = ifelse(
    is.na(Subject),
    Email,
    str_extract(Subject, pattern = "(?<=developer_id=).*(?=&app_id)")
  ))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Email      Subject                                   
#>   <chr>      <chr>                                     
#> 1 a@site.com developer_id=a@site.com&app_id=a&appname=a
#> 2 b@site.com developer_id=b@site.com&app_id=b&appname=b
#> 3 c@site.com <NA>                                      
#> 4 d@site.com developer_id=d@site.com&app_id=d&appname=d
```